# Align a DIV along other elements on the same line, inside a TD

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need Column 3 to look just like Column 1.

I see it behaves that way because of the DIV. If I take it out, it works.

Criteria:

- There must be a DIV inside Column 3 (it is out of my control);
- I'd like Column 3 to occupy 50% of the table;
- Shouldn't need to add another elements to wrap the others
- BUTTON can have a fixed width;
- SELECT should fill all available space of TD.

I could add `float: left` or `display: inline-block` to DIV, but I would also need the `select` to stretch.

I'm using Bootstrap, so it is ok to suggest it, given it satifies criteria.

```css
table {
  background: yellow;
}

td {
  border: red 2px solid;
}
```

```html
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="person">
          <option value="1">Item 1</option>
        </select>
        <button type="button">ADD</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="100">
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <select name="person">
            <option value="1">Item 1</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <button type="button">ADD</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: wheres the rest of your CSS?

Comment: Can you put the button in the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by:

1. Making the third `td` a flex container.
2. Making only its `div` child a flex element.
3. Styling the `select` as 100% width.
4. Styling the third `th` as 50% width.

**Snippet:**

```css
table {
  background: yellow;
}

td {
  border: red 2px solid;
}

td:nth-child(3) {
  display: flex;
}

td:nth-child(3) div {
  flex: 1;
}

td:nth-child(3) select {
  width: 100%;
}

th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="person">
          <option value="1">Item 1</option>
        </select>
        <button type="button">ADD</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="100">
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>
          <select name="person">
            <option value="1">Item 1</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <button type="button">ADD</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: `th` needs to be `width:100%`, in my case. other than that, it worked well. thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this CSS:

```
table {
   background: yellow;
}

td {
   border: red 2px solid;
}

table th:nth-child(3) {
   width:50%;
}

table td:nth-child(3) div{
   width:80%;
   float:left;
   display: table;
}

table td:nth-child(3) button{
   width:20%;
}

table td:nth-child(3) select{
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but the requirement was for the `button´ to have fixed width.